# Install C# plugin for Eclipse

Tags: software-installation, c#

I've been trying to install a C# IDE or C# programming support on my Redhat Workstation, but no luck. I couldn't get Monodevelop running. Now I get these errors on the emonic plugin install for eclipse:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=PlatformProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unknown Host: http://internap.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic/edu.arizona.cs.mbel2_1.9.0.jar
internap.dl.sourceforge.net
Unknown Host: http://internap.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic/org.emonic.base_0.4.0.jar
internap.dl.sourceforge.net
Unknown Host: http://internap.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic/org.emonic.base.build.ant_0.4.0.jar
internap.dl.sourceforge.net
Unknown Host: http://internap.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic/org.emonic.base.build.csant_0.4.0.jar
internap.dl.sourceforge.net
Unknown Host: http://internap.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic/org.emonic.base.build.msbuild_0.4.0.jar
internap.dl.sourceforge.net
Unknown Host: http://internap.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic/org.emonic.base.build.nant_0.4.0.jar
internap.dl.sourceforge.net
Unknown Host: http://internap.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic/org.emonic.debug.core_0.4.0.jar
internap.dl.sourceforge.net
Unknown Host: http://internap.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic/org.emonic.debug.remote_0.4.0.jar
internap.dl.sourceforge.net
Unknown Host: http://internap.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic/org.emonic.debug.ui_0.4.0.jar
internap.dl.sourceforge.net
Unknown Host: http://internap.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic/org.emonic.debugger_0.4.0.jar
internap.dl.sourceforge.net
Unknown Host: http://internap.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic/org.emonic.monodoc_0.4.0.jar
internap.dl.sourceforge.net
```

I'm trying to install this plugin:[link to website](http://emonic.sourceforge.net/html/downloadinfos.html)

Anyone got any ideas on C# for RHEL 6.5 Workstation?

EDIT: This is the errors when I changed to the link to the link from my first answer:

```
`An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=PlatformProfile,
phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
action=).
Unknown Host: http://ovh.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic
/edu.arizona.cs.mbel2_1.9.0.jar
ovh.dl.sourceforge.net
Unknown Host: http://ovh.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic
/org.emonic.base_0.4.0.jar
ovh.dl.sourceforge.net
Unknown Host: http://ovh.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic
/org.emonic.base.build.ant_0.4.0.jar
ovh.dl.sourceforge.net
Unknown Host: http://ovh.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic
/org.emonic.base.build.csant_0.4.0.jar
ovh.dl.sourceforge.net
Unknown Host: http://ovh.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic
/org.emonic.base.build.msbuild_0.4.0.jar
ovh.dl.sourceforge.net
Unknown Host: http://ovh.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic
/org.emonic.base.build.nant_0.4.0.jar
ovh.dl.sourceforge.net
Unknown Host: http://ovh.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic
/org.emonic.debug.core_0.4.0.jar
ovh.dl.sourceforge.net
Unknown Host: http://ovh.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic
/org.emonic.debug.remote_0.4.0.jar
ovh.dl.sourceforge.net
Unknown Host: http://ovh.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic
/org.emonic.debug.ui_0.4.0.jar
ovh.dl.sourceforge.net
Unknown Host: http://ovh.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic
/org.emonic.debugger_0.4.0.jar
ovh.dl.sourceforge.net
Unknown Host: http://ovh.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/emonic
/org.emonic.monodoc_0.4.0.jar
ovh.dl.sourceforge.net`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know from where you got those links/hosts, but they are dead. Try to replace them with the ones included in the [Download via update site](http://emonic.sourceforge.net/html/downloadinfos.html#Download+via+update+site) section:

> Add one of the following update sites to Your Exlipse update configuration (Menu: Help->Software updates->Find and Install)
>
> - http://emonic.sourceforge.net/updatesite/internap/site.xml    San Jose, CA - North America
> - http://emonic.sourceforge.net/updatesite/nchc/site.xml    Tainan, Taiwan - Asia
> - http://emonic.sourceforge.net/updatesite/ovh/site.xml    Paris, France - Europe

I tested those, and the work just fine.

---

Found the issue, those XML files include links to 3rd parties sites which were SourceForge mirrors some time. Apparently, the only way to go is using the [other way](http://emonic.sourceforge.net/html/downloadinfos.html#Download+via+sourceforge) and manually downloading the packages and placing them into the proper directories.

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/emonic/files/emonic/0.4.0/emonic_0.4.0.zip/download

Just unzip the file into your eclipse installation directory (/usr/share/eclipse/dropins) and things should be fine.